# Unable to create AWS UserPool login on a single page app

Tags: jquery, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Im building a single page app that uses AWS UserPools to manage the user login/credentials.

As I want to use further services after login so the projected flow is;

UserPool-> FederatedIdentity -> API Gateway

Reading the docs at: https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-auth-js
I loaded:

```
<!-- AWS JS -->
<script src="js/aws-cognito-sdk.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/amazon-cognito-identity.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.162.0.min.js"></script>
```

When I go to run the usecase 4 code - the page errors with:

```
aws-cognito-sdk.js:11972:42
```

Console log:

```
callListeners
aws-cognito-sdk.js:11972:42
emit
aws-cognito-sdk.js:11944:4
emitEvent
aws-cognito-sdk.js:11571:4
a
aws-cognito-sdk.js:11300:4
[52]</d.prototype.runTo
aws-cognito-sdk.js:13172:2
[52]</d.prototype.runTo/<
aws-cognito-sdk.js:13184:4
a/<
aws-cognito-sdk.js:11316:8
emitEvent/<
aws-cognito-sdk.js:11573:6
callListeners
aws-cognito-sdk.js:11980:4
emit
aws-cognito-sdk.js:11944:4
emitEvent
aws-cognito-sdk.js:11571:4
a
aws-cognito-sdk.js:11300:4
[52]</d.prototype.runTo
aws-cognito-sdk.js:13172:2
[52]</d.prototype.runTo/<
aws-cognito-sdk.js:13184:4
a/<
aws-cognito-sdk.js:11316:8
emitEvent/<
aws-cognito-sdk.js:11573:6
callListeners
aws-cognito-sdk.js:11980:4
emit
aws-cognito-sdk.js:11944:4
emitEvent
aws-cognito-sdk.js:11571:4
a
aws-cognito-sdk.js:11300:4
[52]</d.prototype.runTo
aws-cognito-sdk.js:13172:2
[52]</d.prototype.runTo/<
aws-cognito-sdk.js:13184:4
a/<
aws-cognito-sdk.js:11316:8
emitEvent/<
aws-cognito-sdk.js:11573:6
callListeners
aws-cognito-sdk.js:11980:4
emit
aws-cognito-sdk.js:11944:4
emitEvent
aws-cognito-sdk.js:11571:4
a
aws-cognito-sdk.js:11300:4
[52]</d.prototype.runTo
aws-cognito-sdk.js:13172:2
[52]</d.prototype.runTo/<
aws-cognito-sdk.js:13184:4
a/<
aws-cognito-sdk.js:11316:8
emitEvent/<
aws-cognito-sdk.js:11573:6
callListeners
aws-cognito-sdk.js:11980:4
f
aws-cognito-sdk.js:11960:6
c/<
aws-cognito-sdk.js:9255:10
[60]</d.prototype.emit
aws-cognito-sdk.js:15537:8
finishRequest
aws-cognito-sdk.js:9730:4
handleRequest/<
aws-cognito-sdk.js:9655:8
```

Here is a copy of my modified sample code:

```
var authenticationData = {
        Username : 'mytestusername',
        Password : 'mytestpassword',
    };
    var authenticationDetails = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
    var poolData = {
        UserPoolId : 'us-east-1_777', // Your user pool id here
        ClientId : 'myclientidfromuserpools' // Your client id here
    };
    var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
    var userData = {
        Username : 'mytestusername',
        Pool : userPool
    };
    var cognitoUser = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser(userData);
    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
        onSuccess: function (result) {
            console.log('access token + ' + result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken());

        //POTENTIAL: Region needs to be set if not already set previously elsewhere.
        AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';

        AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
            IdentityPoolId : 'us-east-1:myfederatedID', // your identity pool id here
            Logins : {
                // Change the key below according to the specific region your user pool is in.
                'cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-myfederatedID' : result.getIdToken().getJwtToken()
            }
        });

        //refreshes credentials using AWS.CognitoIdentity.getCredentialsForIdentity()
        AWS.config.credentials.refresh((error) => {
            if (error) {
                 console.error(error);
            } else {
                 // Instantiate aws sdk service objects now that the credentials have been updated.
                 // example: var s3 = new AWS.S3();
                 console.log('Successfully logged!');
            }
        });
    },

    onFailure: function(err) {
        alert(err);
    },

});
```

I dont understand whats going with AWS JS to be able to figure out how to fix. 
Im trying to keep the login inside the SinglePageApp rather than use the AWS hosted and redirects. 
Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the unminified versions of the scripts available in the same repos and Google Chrome developer tools to get a more descriptive error.

Comment: aws-cognito-sdk.js:11972 Uncaught Error: callback.newPasswordRequired is not a function
    at amazon-cognito-identity.js:1891
    at Response.<anonymous> (amazon-cognito-identity.js:1855)
    at Request.<anonymous> (aws-cognito-sdk.js:11371)
    at Request.callListeners (aws-cognito-sdk.js:11970)
    at Request.emit (aws-cognito-sdk.js:11944)
    at Request.emit (aws-cognito-sdk.js:11571)
    at Request.transition (aws-cognito-sdk.js:11300)at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (aws-cognito-sdk.js:13172)
at aws-cognito-sdk.js:13184
at Request.<anonymous> (aws-cognito-sdk.js:11316)

Comment: You basically need to provide that callback in case you are using admin created users.